# PHP Классы, чем они лучше

Tags: классы, php

Чем лучше ООП от обычных функций с глобальными переменами $GLOBALS[]? По мне так кода становится больше:

1. + переменые работают внутри только одного класса
2. - долгая инициализация класса (возрастает нагрузка на 10% при вызове класса)
3. - не понятно как работает include
4. можно создать переменую внутри одного класса и получить ее внутри другого класса или возможно использовать константы или глобальные переменные?

Comment: А что не понятно с include?
По 4-му пункту, да можно путем наследования если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Прочитайте про паттерн Registry.

Comment: Внутри класса не подгружает файл через include или require.

Comment: Они лучше тем, что сложность PHP-каши снижается и превращается во что-то чуть более осязаемое, чем это GLOBALS-крошево.

Comment: PHP сам по себе - тормоза) Хотите производительности - пишите на асме, а классы - удобный инструмент. Кроме того, сотня функций с префиксами смотрится просто ужасно (`mystring_concat, mystring_split` etc.)

>> Внутри класса не подгружает файл через include или require.

Это вам кто сказал? о_О Пути-то проверяйте, откуда вызываете.

Comment: незнай, внутри класса ставлю include или require - выходят ошибка, в не класса переношу все ок, может в настройка php.ini надо копать

и еще у меня три файла в каждом по 30-40 мелких функций + еще один файл в нем всего 10 функций, но по размеру он самый здоровый, отвечающий за контент на сайте (для загрузки внешних файлов в хедер, для боди текст, выбор шаблонов и тд), так вот как все эти функции лучше всего перенести в класс, собрать в один большой файл и обьявить его классом или как-нибудь подругому по изящнее, есть предложения?

Comment: > или как-нибудь подругому по изящнее, есть предложения?
Есть. Все удалить и начать писать с нуля ;)

А если серьезно, то нету ни какого смысла запихивать кучу существующих функций в класс. Если хотите понять зачем нужны классы - изучайте ООП, иначе лучше оставьте все как есть и работайте только с функциями.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос поставлен не корректно. Классы/объекты != [ООП](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (вы ведь имели ввиду ООП? Т.к. по запросу ОПП [гугл выдает](http://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%9E%D0%9F%D0%9F) сайт "Общество психоаналитической психотерапии")

[ООП](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) - это парадигма, которая держится на трех китах: наследование, полиморфизм, инкапсуляция. Классы/объекты, по сути, являются лишь средством для реализации этой парадигмы.

Более детально про [ООП](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и [процедурное программирование](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) можете прочитать, к примеру, в wikipedia.

Comment: Или скачайnте Энди Гутманс "Профессиональное программирование на PHP5". Еще мануал скачайте, чтобы не придумывать велосипед.

Comment: Неа, не дает покоя - классы это круто, значит надо переводит на класы

я почему хочу имено создать идеальную кмс для себе

до этого я фигачил сайты на джумле, модх, дле и тд. в месяц по 5-7 сайтов. по мере работе вырабатывался стандартный шаблон, к каждой кмс, в котом были: дефалтовый css, jquery, плагин для всяких эфектов и тд. Но все это ниче, когда собираешь  сайт на своей кмс, когда тот же tinymce, но с добавлеными фишками для авто ресайза изображения, вставки видео и тд. когда это от проекта к проекту улучшается, а время на создание сайта уменьшается.

Comment: вот поэтому я и хочу переписать движуху, но с классами у меня только общее представление. Да и на техже МодХ, ДЛЕ и прочие кмски.
поэтому мне нужны советы, грамотные советы для начало как лучше начать работать, а то можно потерять кучу времени.

Answer (score 1):

Классы и их объекты - это удобный способ делать большие и гибко масштабируемые проекты.

К примеру: в проекте "автомобиль", для того чтобы воспользоваться объектом "автомагнитола", не обязательно знать основы радиосигналов, достаточно просто запустить public-метод "включить". Реализация класса "автомагнитола" в одном месте (модуле), а логика проекта "автомобиль", где используется этот объект - в другом.

Мухи отдельно, компот отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Плюсы использования классов:

1. удобство использования сторонними программистами
   То есть, вы пишете класс, составляете его документацию и передаете сторонему разработчику. При этом ему совершенно не важно, что происходит внутри класса. Он лишь знает, что у методов класса на входе и что на выходе.
2. более простое расширение возможностей
   Оно же наследование, оно же полиформизм. То есть, есть возможность объединить функционал нескольких классов в одном или изменить функционал класса, не изменяя его интерфейс.
3. закрытость кода (относительная)
   Есть возможность настроить переменные и методы класса так, чтобы они были недоступны извне.
4. классы меньше засоряют пространство имен
   Есть один экземпляр класса - и все. Все переменные у него внутри.

Минусы:

1. да, работа через классы происходит медленнее, чем через функции